# Organizing a Flask project

Tags: python, flask

This is my first time creating a project using python and flask. I intend to use SQLAlchemy models along too. and this is a fairly bigger project. As of now, I have divided the project in 2 Blueprints : site and the api. After organizing the project, I am confused as to how can I connnect these models with the database and do I need to re-organize the structure as I am not fully aware of nature of flask.

so this is the directory structure of the dir `app/` in my base repository:

`

```
.
├── Blueprints
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── routes.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── config.py
│   └── site
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   └── routes.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── operations.py
│       ├── routes.py
│       ├── static
│       └── templates
│           ├── about.html
│           ├── contact.html
│           ├── home.html
│           ├── login.html
│           ├── services.html
│           └── stories.html
├── __main__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __main__.cpython-36.pyc
└── models
    ├── Attendance.py
    ├── Batch.py
    ├── Course.py
    ├── Module.py
    ├── Student.py
    ├── Test.py
    └── __init__.py
```

`

Please ignore Pycache, as this is auto generated.

now I cannot figure out a way as to how to import and use these models in api and site, neither I can understand as to how am I supposed to fetch the db object created in `/Blueprints/__init__.py` to all the models.

I understand that this question is not upto the standards of stack overflow questions, BUT I personally feel that organizing a flask project is itself very confusing with each tutorial or forum I see, having their own perspectives of organizing it.

Comment: When in trouble, always refer to the official documentation. There maybe many ways to solve a problem but the docs are quite comprehensive and straightforward with lots of examples and will always give you accurate information.I've found [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#templates) you might find helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several ways to organize a project, but the `__init__.py` file contained inside the app/ folder is what links a lot of it together. Here's the contents of one of my project's `__init__.py` file:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
from flask import Flask, session
from app.config import (PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME_MS, Time_Before_Warning,
                        Min_Ping_Interval)
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

# Setup the app with the config.py file
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

# Setup the logger
from app.logger_setup import logger, log_view

# Setup the database
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#setup zipcode database
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zdb = ZipCodeDatabase()

# Setup the mail server
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
mail = Mail(app)

# Setup the debug toolbar
#from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
#app.config['DEBUG_TB_TEMPLATE_EDITOR_ENABLED'] = False
#app.config['DEBUG_TB_PROFILER_ENABLED'] = False
#toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

# Setup the password crypting
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

# Import the views
from app.views import (main, user, error, request, upload, dashboard, org,
                        msgs, notifications, download, reports,
                        direct_send,provider,utils)
app.register_blueprint(user.userbp)
app.register_blueprint(request.requestbp)
app.register_blueprint(upload.uploadbp)
app.register_blueprint(dashboard.dashboardbp)
app.register_blueprint(org.orgbp)
app.register_blueprint(msgs.msgbp)
app.register_blueprint(notifications.notificationsbp)
app.register_blueprint(download.downloadbp)
app.register_blueprint(reports.reportsbp)
app.register_blueprint(direct_send.directsendbp)
app.register_blueprint(provider.providerbp)
app.register_blueprint(utils.utilsbp)

# Setup the user login process
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, current_user
from app.models import User, View

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'userbp.signin'


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
    return User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()

from flask.ext.principal import identity_loaded, RoleNeed, UserNeed
@identity_loaded.connect_via(app)
def on_identity_loaded(sender, identity):

    # Set the identity user object
    identity.user = current_user

    # Add the UserNeed to the identity
    if hasattr(current_user, 'id'):
        identity.provides.add(UserNeed(current_user.id))

    # Assuming the User model has a list of roles, update the
    # identity with the roles that the user provides
    if hasattr(current_user, 'roles'):
        identity.provides.add(RoleNeed(current_user.roles.type))

from flask.ext.principal import Principal

# load the extension
principals = Principal(app)

# Create a permission with a single Need, in this case a RoleNeed.

#from app import admin

@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    lt = PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME_MS / (60*1000)
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=lt)

@app.context_processor
def add_session_config():
    """
    Add current_app.permanent_session_lifetime converted to milliseconds
    to context.
    """
    return {
        'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME_MS': PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME_MS,
        'Time_Before_Warning': Time_Before_Warning,
        'Min_Ping_Interval': Min_Ping_Interval,
    }
```

And then inside one of the blueprints:

```
from flask import (Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for,
                   abort, flash, request)
from flask.ext.login import login_required, current_user
from app import app, models, db, log_view, config
from app.models import (Groups, Organizations, OrgHasOwner, UserHasGroups,
                        GroupHasOwner, User, Fax, FavoriteGroups)
from app.forms import org as org_forms
from app.toolbox import email, misc, s3, fax
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from uuid import uuid4
import datetime
import string
import os

# Create a user blueprint
orgbp = Blueprint('orgbp', __name__, url_prefix='/org')

@orgbp.route('/invite_user', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def invite_user():
    [stuff goes here]
```